# Javascript - Push object in an array only if it does not already exists

Tags: javascript

**Overview:**

I have like 10 "add to cart" buttons in one page (10 different products), when the user clicks on "addToCart" button, the item should be added to the array **this.itemsInCart** if it does not already exists on the array while the quantity is set to '1'; however, if the item exists already it should only increment the quantity of that item in the array.

**The problem:**

The problem shows up after adding the second product to the cart (*for the second time*), it increments the quantity of that product but on the same time it creates a new object of the same object with the same id with a quantity of 1.

**The current code:**

```
  addToCart(itemDetails) {
if (this.itemsInCart.length == 0) {
  this.itemsInCart.push({
    itemId: itemDetails.objectId,
    itemName: itemDetails.dishName,
    itemPrice: itemDetails.price,
    qty: 1,
  })
} else {
  this.itemsInCart.forEach(el => {
  if (el.itemId == itemDetails.objectId) {
      el.qty += 1;
      return;
    } else if (el.itemId != itemDetails.objectId) {
      this.itemsInCart.push({
        itemId: itemDetails.objectId,
        itemName: itemDetails.dishName,
        itemPrice: itemDetails.price,
        qty: 1,
      })
    }

  })
  }
 }
```

**Generated array showing the issue :**

```
        [
      {
        "itemId": "zMrEXUEx7U",
        "itemName": "Roller Menu",
        "itemPrice": 27.5,
        "qty": 2
      },
      {
        "itemId": "AD9cZs4R4A",
        "itemName": "Big Filler Smokey Menu",
        "itemPrice": 66,
        "qty": 2
      },
      {
        "itemId": "zMrEXUEx7U",
        "itemName": "Roller Menu",
        "itemPrice": 27.5,
        "qty": 1
      },
      {
        "itemId": "AD9cZs4R4A",
        "itemName": "Big Filler Smokey Menu",
        "itemPrice": 66,
        "qty": 1
      },
      {
        "itemId": "AD9cZs4R4A",
        "itemName": "Big Filler Smokey Menu",
        "itemPrice": 66,
        "qty": 1
      }
    ]
```

Comment: If you have no synchronicity issue, use `find` instead of `forEach`. Or use an object `{}` instead of an array `[]` to guarantee key uniqueness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not push in `.forEach()`. You need to set a flag (ex. `exists`), default to `false` and when you find item in `.forEach` callback update this flag to `true`.

When flag is `false` push to array.

```
let flag = false;

this.itemsInCart.forEach(el => {
    if (el.itemId == itemDetails.objectId) {
        el.qty += 1;

        flag = true;

        return false;
    }
})

if (!flag) {
    this.itemsInCart.push({
        itemId: itemDetails.objectId,
        itemName: itemDetails.dishName,
        itemPrice: itemDetails.price,
        qty: 1
    });
}
```